# Check if the user input matches one of the elements in the array

Tags: c

If the user inputs a value that matches with an `int` in the array continue the program else quit the program.
My issue is that the function loops the whole array and if it finds one of the values doesnt match it will quit.

```
//Check if the user input matches with one of the ints in the array
void check(int num, int arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != num) {
            printf("Invalid input");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    int arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\nPLease enter a value which matches with the array %d", num);
    scanf("%d", &num);
    check(num, arr);
}
```

Comment: If `arr` is unbounded, you might look into a hashset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logic flaw in the `check` function: you should output the message and quit if **none** of the values match the input. You instead do this if one of the values does not match. The `check` always fails.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Check if the user input matches with one of the ints in the array
void check(int num, const int arr[], size_t len) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == num) {
            // value found, just return to the caller
            return;
        }
    }
    // if we get here, none of the values in the array match num
    printf("Invalid input: %d\n", num);
    exit(1);
}

int main() {
    int arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    size_t len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr); // length of the array
    int num;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Please enter a value which matches with the array: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &num) == 1) {
        check(num, arr, len);
    } else {
        // input missing or not a number
        printf("Invalid input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked perfectly, I was so stuck on the for loop going through each value in the array.

Comment: This does work, but it is better to send the size of the array to the function too, rather than using a magic number.

Comment: @alonkh2: you are absolutely right, it is much better to pass the array length as an argument. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
void check(int num, int arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == num) {
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Invalid input");
    exit(0);
}
```

Your issue is that checks a single element and judges the input on that specific value. If it has run through each value and the function has still not returned, there is not match and we can exit the program.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you do exit once `arr[i] != num` (When the value is **not** the same as the *i:th* element in the array).

So, you could change it to: `arr[i] == num`. If it *is* the same, perhaps print "You got it!", and a [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/return-statement-c?view=msvc-170) afterwards.